# Number of possibilities to choose class representatives

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Question**: A school has 4 classes. Each class consists of 25 students. The school needs to choose 10 class representatives, in which there is a minimum of one student from each class. How many ways there are to do so?

I get why the final answer, using inclusion/exclusion, will be: $${{100}\choose{10}} - {{4}\choose{3}}{{75}\choose{10}} + {{4}\choose{2}}{{50}\choose{10}} - {{4}\choose{1}}{{25}\choose{10}}$$

But, why couldn't I do something like the following: First, I need to assure that there 4 students, each representing a separate class. In total, there are $25^{4}$ ways of doing so. After that, I can choose the 6 available slots for the class representatives from the $100-4 = 96$ students left, meaning that there are ${96}\choose{6}$ ways of doing so. In total, from what I just described, where would be a total of: $${25^{4}}*{{96}\choose{6}}$$ possibilities for the selection.

Conceptually I must be getting something wrong. What am I over-counting/under-counting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be a over-counting. Say students in classes $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are named such as $a_1,...,a_{25}$ for class $A$; $b_1,...,b_{25}$ for class $B$; $c_1,...,c_{25}$ for class $C$, $d_1,...,d_{25}$ for class $D$. Then when we choose one student from each class first, assume we have chosen $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$ and $d_1$. Then assume, rest of the students are $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$, $a_6$ and $a_7$. But, this is as same as chosing $a_2$ first instead of $a_1$, then choosing $a_1$, $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$, $a_6$ and $a_7$. So we are overcounting.

**NOTE:** You can easily see that the example I gave is not the only case we are counting more than once.

Comment: All cases are over counted.  The case you cited is counted seven times, once for each way you could designate a representative of class A as the person whose spot is reserved for a representative of class A.

Comment: Yes, now I can see the flaws in my intuition for solving these kinds of questions. The fact that each student is distinct causes multiple over counting in the supposed calculation I provided. Thanks for pointing it out! Much appreciated!

Comment: @0rka You're welcome :) As long as people here not only ask questions but also add their own attempts, it is easier for us to help too so thank you too.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes you are right. And since for different examples we count different many times, I think we can't simply divide ${25^{4}} \cdot {{96}\choose{6}}$ by $7$. Inclusion-Exclusion Principle guarantees the solution.

Comment: That is correct.  For instance, a distribution of $(6, 2, 1, 1)$ is counted $\binom{6}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1} = 12$ times.  In my experience, this type of question arises frequently.  You handled the explanation well.

Comment: Oh, I knew that there was overcounting but I didn't know how to determine how many times we over-counted. Thank you for the explanation :) Next time if I see a question like this one, I will also try to add the information you just gave.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Interesting observation, and a good verdict to why we can't simply divide $25^{4} \cdot {{96}\choose{6}}$ by an integer (like 7, which was pointed out in earlier comments). Thanks for the clarification.